# Deploying a Cloud Function from Cloud Build with --allow-unauthenticated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

My goal is to deploy a Cloud Function using Cloud Build.  My `cloudbuild.yaml` looks as follows:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: 
    [
      'functions', 'deploy', 'func3',
      '--region=us-central1',
      '--allow-unauthenticated',
      '--entry-point=helloWorld',
      '--runtime=nodejs8',
      '--source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/XXX/repos/myfunc',
      '--trigger-http',
      '--service-account=XXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
    ]
```

When I submit the build, the following is logged:

```
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/builds/5ba01de5-b4ad-4489-b4b9-687d3a6fd8fa].
Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/5ba01de5-b4ad-4489-b4b9-687d3a6fd8fa?project=YYY].
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
starting build "5ba01de5-b4ad-4489-b4b9-687d3a6fd8fa"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: --allow-unauthenticated 

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 5ba01de5-b4ad-4489-b4b9-687d3a6fd8fa completed with status "FAILURE"
```

As we can see, we fail.  If I remove the line which references `--allow-unauthenticated` all proceeds correctly.  For completeness, here is the working `cloudbuild.yaml`.

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: 
    [
      'functions', 'deploy', 'func3',
      '--region=us-central1',
      '--entry-point=helloWorld',
      '--runtime=nodejs8',
      '--source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/XXX/repos/myfunc',
      '--trigger-http',
      '--service-account=XXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'
    ]
```

I have checked the gcloud documentation on `gcloud functions deploy` found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--allow-unauthenticated) and can't see any typos or other trivial errors.  I have been assuming that running `gcloud` as a Cloud Builder step would be identical to running it manually.

If I run the command manually (including the `--allow-unauthenticated`) it works without error.  For example, if I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcloud functions deploy func3 \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --entry-point=helloWorld \
    --runtime=nodejs8 \
    --source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/XXX/repos/myfunc \
    --trigger-http \
    --service-account=XXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

... there are no issues.

The core of the question is what might be the issue with the `--allow-unauthenticated` option within the context of Cloud Build?

Comment: for kicks, try using `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud@sha256:4ea77d19d7336d5a8dc4ae0e609d7f5b45fca067c34b70d7ed6740af229392c6` as the build image. I've seen a couple weird errors like this in the past day.

Comment: I tried the builder using the incantation described where my `cloudbuild.yaml` contained the `--allow-unauthenticated` and this time got no error.  I'm curious as to how you (mr Travis) came to find this recipe and your thinking behind it.  Are we saying that this is simple a *transient* condition and that sooner or later the issue I'm having will just disappear?   Happy to follow y'alls recommendation about the fate of this question.  I'm leaning to deleting it as a *glitch*...

Comment: @Kolban it might still be useful for others facing the same issue, despite it's likely just a temporary issue cause by a) asynchronous versions of the back-ends which they've deployed or b) the image used (rather the second in this case). You still could notify them by opening a ticket.

Comment: It was a total shot in the dark, because that error makes no sense. You appear to be doing everything right AFAIK. It means that the latest gcloud build image has a bug. you can find old versions here: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/gcloud?gcrImageListsize=30

Comment: What are the role granted to cloudbuild service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a transient issue caused by a faulty `gcloud` build image.

Use this version for now:

```
gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud@sha256:4ea77d19d7336d5a8dc4ae0e609d7f5b45fca067c34b70d7ed6740af229392c6
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message might be a little misleading:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: --allow-unauthenticated
```

When running  `gcloud help functions deploy` it lists `--allow-unauthenticated` as a valid flag:

```
--allow-unauthenticated
    If set, makes this a public function. This will allow all callers,
    without checking authentication.
```

---

As Travis commented... that this could be erroneous behavior isn't something I'd consider as "unlikely", since occasional glitches are nothing special when complex distributed systems are being updated.

Comment: Howdy Martin and thanks for the response.  The unrecognized argument message would seem to indicate that the option `--allow-unauthenticated` is not valid yet when I look at the gcloud functions deploy command, it appears to be present.  The README for the builder claims "Arguments passed to this builder will be passed to gcloud directly, allowing callers to run any gcloud command.".  Are there only a subset of options supported?